# `useEffect` to add to state without entering infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3001/get_users/per_page/10/page_number/0`
    );
    setUsers([...users, ...result.data.users]);
    setListUsersQueryState("complete");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const loadMore = () => {
    fetchUsers();
  };
```

`useEffect` should be called initially on load hence the `[]` as dependencies. It should then be called each time a 'load more' button is pressed.

With the above code react complains

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchUsers'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

Answer (score 1):

React `useEffect` hook takes a first parameter. The right way to do this is not to set a dependency on users, but to get the value of `users` at the time it's set like this:

```
setUsers(users => [...users, ...result.data.users]);
```

Now it doesn't go into an infinite loop, but react is still happy that the dependency is satisfied.